# getting 403 forbidden error using httpd (apache) connecting to tomcat via AJP

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-jk, ajp, tomcat9

i am staring to be little bit hopeless since i tried many solutions and nothing worked.
I am getting 403 Forbidden error when i try to reach my apache Tomcat server via httpd server (used as loadbalancer), directly i am able to reach Tomcat.

Using: apache httpd 2.4.57
mod_jk 1.49 - (to connect to tomcat)
Tomcat 9.0.6
Both servers are Rhel9.2

mod_jk.log thorws:

```
AJP13 protocol: Reuse is set to false
```

When i switch logging to debug:

```
[Tue Mar 05 11:40:46 2024] [ZecEvlLNAdbkYeD1ZVBPVQAAAAM] [1081073:139915513611840] [warn] ajp_process_callback::jk_ajp_common.c (2195): (imsWorker) AJP13 protocol: Reuse is set to false
[Tue Mar 05 11:40:46 2024] [ZecEvlLNAdbkYeD1ZVBPVQAAAAM] [1081073:139915513611840] [debug] ajp_reset_endpoint::jk_ajp_common.c (874): (imsWorker) resetting endpoint with socket 31 (socket shutdown)
[Tue Mar 05 11:40:46 2024] [ZecEvlLNAdbkYeD1ZVBPVQAAAAM] [1081073:139915513611840] [debug] ajp_abort_endpoint::jk_ajp_common.c (844): (imsWorker) aborting endpoint with socket 31
[Tue Mar 05 11:40:46 2024] [ZecEvlLNAdbkYeD1ZVBPVQAAAAM] [1081073:139915513611840] [debug] jk_shutdown_socket::jk_connect.c (933): About to shutdown socket 31 [172.10.2.36:38684 -> 172.10.2.52:8009]
[Tue Mar 05 11:40:46 2024] [ZecEvlLNAdbkYeD1ZVBPVQAAAAM] [1081073:139915513611840] [debug] jk_is_input_event::jk_connect.c (1414): error event during poll on socket 31 [errno=107] (event=16)
[Tue Mar 05 11:40:46 2024] [ZecEvlLNAdbkYeD1ZVBPVQAAAAM] [1081073:139915513611840] [debug] jk_shutdown_socket::jk_connect.c (1017): Shutdown socket 31 [172.10.2.36:38684 -> 172.10.2.52:8009] and read 0 lingering bytes in 0 sec.
[Tue Mar 05 11:40:46 2024] [ZecEvlLNAdbkYeD1ZVBPVQAAAAM] [1081073:139915513611840] [debug] ajp_done::jk_ajp_common.c (3411): recycling connection pool for worker imsWorker and socket -1
[Tue Mar 05 11:40:46 2024] [ZecEvlLNAdbkYeD1ZVBPVQAAAAM] [1081073:139915513611840] [debug] jk_handler::mod_jk.c (3009): Service finished with status=403 for worker=imsWorker
```

AJP Connector on tomcat server:

```
<Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool" port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" address="::" redirectPort="8443" secretRequired="true" secret="test147258369!" connectionTimeout="10000" allowedRequestAttributesPattern=".*" relaxedQueryChars="[]" />
```

worker.properties on apache machine:

```
worker.list=imsWorker
worker.imsWorker.type=ajp13
worker.imsWorker.host=172.10.2.52
worker.imsWorker.port=8009
wokrer.imsWorker.secret=test147258369!
worker.imsWorker.connect_timeout=10000
worker.imsWorker.prepost_timeout=10000
worker.imsWorker.socket_timeout=10
worker.imsWorker.connection_pool_timeout=60
worker.imsWorker.connection_pool_size=90
worker.imsWorker.retries=2
worker.imsWorker.reply_timeout=30000
```

I already got this to work on different machines with RockyOs9.2 and didn't face this issue
Help will be appreciated.
Thanks

I also tried disabling secret by setting secretRequired to false on tomcat, but issue persisted, so i don't think this is related to secret attribute.